# Demo code is throwing a out_of_range exception but I don't know why

Tags: c++, string, exception, indexoutofboundsexception

I am writing code in C++ to remove any two consecutive characters which are the same. 
for example:

```
 - aa -> empty string 
 - aabb -> empty string 
 - abba -> aa -> empty string (as removal of 'bb' makes it 'aa') 
 - abab -> abab (not possible)
```

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i;
    string s;
    bool match = true;
    getline(cin, s);
    while (match) {
        match = false;
        for (i = 0; i < s.length() - 1; i++) {
            if (s.at(i) == s.at(i+1)) {
                s.erase(i,2);
                match = true;
           }
        }
    }
    if (s == "") {
        cout << "Empty!";
    }
    else {
        cout << s;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What string is bringing the error? What's the error case?

Comment: or you can just `std::regex_replace(s, std::regex("(.)\\1{1}"), "");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`s.length()` is unsigned and `s.length() - 1` will be very big when `s.length()` is 0.

You should check if `s.length()` is zero before performing subtraction like this:

```
for (i = 0; s.length() > 0 && i < s.length() - 1; i++) {
```

Comment: A simpler alternative is to move the -1 to the other side: `i + 1 < s.length()`